# Ionic / Refresh button issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, page-refresh

I have a refresh button on one of my pages. I have populated the table with json data . The json data is set to the cache and then moved to the view. Now i need to know how to refresh the page . Using ionic ofcourse...thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not able to post it as comment so I'm posting it as an answer.
Have a look at this http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/

Hope this will help.